# Sequence between timestamps IBM SPSS Modeler

Tags: timestamp, sequence, spss, spss-modeler

I'm facing a problem with generating a time sequence in seconds between two timestamps in the IBM SPSS Modeler.
So my trivial data after aggregation looks like this:

```
| start               | end                 |
--------------------------------------------------
| 2015-01-01 12:00:00 | 2015-05-30 12:00:00 |
--------------------------------------------------
```

And my goal is to get this:

```
| start               |
--------------------------------------------------
| 2015-01-01 12:00:00 |
--------------------------------------------------
| 2015-01-01 12:00:00 |
--------------------------------------------------
| 2015-01-01 12:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------
| …                   |
--------------------------------------------------
| 2015-05-30 11:59:59 |
--------------------------------------------------
| 2015-05-30 12:00:00 |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Generating the sequence in R `seq(start, stop, by=1)` works perfectly fine but generates a lot of overhead in the Modeler.

Answer (score 1):

I am not too familiar with modeler but could you find the difference in time (seconds), then loop a derive node that many times and transpose?

This is obviously not a pretty solution but the only one I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

In Modeler 17.1 and lower:

1. Transform it to long format. Split data by two FILTER nodes. First one filters out "end" variable, second one filters out "start" and rename "end" to "start". Then append it with APPEND node.

   ```
   | start|
   | 2015-01-01 12:00:00 |    
   | 2015-05-30 12:00:00 |
   ```
2. Then you can use TIME INTERVALS node set to "Seconds per day" and "Build from data" with "start" variable selected.
3. Don't forget to set "Maximum number of records..." in "Build" panel, else it would lead in most cases to error.

I don't have nice solution for Modeler 18:

- It is possible to use USER INPUT with MERGE then SELECT, BALANCE node or some weird time series model, but it's not elegant and without possibility to use parameters (Python scripting should overcome this, but I didn't try it yet).